# Function should return String but returns (Function)

Tags: swift

After creating an `extension` for an `enum`, I experience something odd.

I want to return a String based on the enum case, but instead I get `Optional((Function))`

Here is a snippet

```
enum ComparisonOperator: String, CaseIterable {
    case equalTo = "equal to"
    case greaterThan = "greater than"
    case greaterThanOrEqualTo = "greater than or equal to"
    case lessThan = "less than"
    case lessThanOrEqualTo = "less than or equal to"
    case differentFrom = "different from"
}

extension ComparisonOperator {
    func shortName() -> String {
        
        switch self {
            case .equalTo:
                return "equalTo"
            case .greaterThan:
                return "greaterThan"
            case .greaterThanOrEqualTo:
                return "greaterThanOrEqualTo"
            case .lessThan:
                return "lessThan"
            case .lessThanOrEqualTo:
                return "lessThanOrEqualTo"
            case .differentFrom:
                return "differentFrom"
        }
    }
}
```

I expect this to return the string value when calling the shortName() after a ComparisonOperator but instead I get the response above.

The test snippet:

```
let comparisonOperator = ComparisonOperator.greaterThanOrEqualTo
print(comparisonOperator.shortName)
```

Expected response:

```
greaterThanOrEqualTo
```

Actual response:

```
Optional((Function))
```

What am I doing wrong? :-)

Comment: I tried your code and I'm getting the expected response. Could the problem be elsewhere?

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik uuuh that's interesting! Let me dig deeper and get back to you :-)

Comment: @LeoDabus .rawValue returns "greater than or equal to" and I need to return another value here "greaterThanOrEqualTo". So two values by the same enum.

Comment: As mentioned by @OmerTekbiyik the code seems to work alright. Also kind of weird that the response statement contains `optional`, considering your actual print doesn't contain any optional. Maybe the response is from something else?

Comment: I suspect that where your problem is actually occurring, you're calling `comparisonOperator.shortName` (resulting in an un-evaluated function), which is different from `comparisonOperator.shortName()`.

Comment: @Alexander true but how its still Optional? something is wrong here
:)

Comment: @Alexander you were right!! Thank you! Post an answer and I'll accept it - if it makes sense :-)  Omer the code example in the question simplified - and somehow I managed to remember the () in the example ;-)

Comment: I have updated the question so the code will act as described.

Comment: @SimonDegn not related to your question but you should simply create a method to convert camelCase to "camel case" instead of manually setting those values. something like `replacingOccurrences(of: #"([a-z])([A-Z])"#, with: "$1 $2", options: .regularExpression).lowercased()`

Comment: @LeoDabus yup, but this was just the simplified code snippet for the question - it does not look like this irl. But thanks :-)

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik Probably `someOptionalComparisonOperator?.shortName`

Comment: In addition , You can do this by adding a computed property to the enum. You don't need to write a function and add an extension for this.

Comment: @Omer please elaborate or link :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that where your problem is actually occurring, you're calling `comparisonOperator.shortName` (resulting in an un-evaluated function), which is different from `comparisonOperator.shortName()`

Answer (score 1):

According to comment

```
enum ComparisonOperator: String, CaseIterable {
    case equalTo = "equal to"
    case greaterThan = "greater than"
    case greaterThanOrEqualTo = "greater than or equal to"
    case lessThan = "less than"
    case lessThanOrEqualTo = "less than or equal to"
    case differentFrom = "different from"

    var shortName : String{
        switch self {
            case .equalTo:
                return "equalTo"
            case .greaterThan:
                return "greaterThan"
            case .greaterThanOrEqualTo:
                return "greaterThanOrEqualTo"
            case .lessThan:
                return "lessThan"
            case .lessThanOrEqualTo:
                return "lessThanOrEqualTo"
            case .differentFrom:
                return "differentFrom"
        }
    }
}

let comparisonOperator = ComparisonOperator.greaterThanOrEqualTo.shortName
print(comparisonOperator)
```

Comment: Aaah cool. Thanks! That's much prettier - didn't know that was possible